# How to convert multiple url to PDF in python

Tags: python

I use BeautifulSoup parsing multiple url and want to convert to PDF. but I don't know how?

my code like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('1.html'),"lxml")
    for i in soup.find_all('a',class_='black'):
        pdfkit.from_url(['http://mycode.com'+i['href']],'1.pdf')
```

If there are two URLs in html. I want to two PDF files, but, it's only one file "1.pdf". How to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always write to the same PDF file: `1.pdf`. You need to tell `pdfkit` to write each URL to a different file. E.g.:

```
for file_id, i in enumerate(soup.find_all('a',class_='black')):
    pdfkit.from_url(['http://mycode.com'+i['href']], str(file_id) + '.pdf')
```